# AWS lambda to access redshift and import external library pyregresql

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-redshift

I am trying to write a lambda function in python, that copies data from an S3 bucket to a Redshift database.

I am following this example to write my code:

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/UnloadCopyUtility/redshift-unload-copy.py

However, I am not able to run the lambda function inline.

It appears that in order to  "import pg", I need to install pyGreSql2 library, which has a dependency on PostGreSql library.

What is the right way to include them in the deployment package?

I am working on Mac , and created a [docker](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/escaping-lambda-function-hell-using-docker-40b187ec1e48)  to prepare lambda deployment package.

When I used the following commands, PyGreSQL was successfully installed, but I got error when I uploaded the zip file in lambda and tested.

```
$sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev
$pip install -t . PyGreSQL
```

Error on lambda:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is the right way to deploy my lambda function with PyGreSQL successfully? Note that I do not want to use psycopg2 library for various reasons.

Thanks.
Swagatika

Comment: can you not use https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-redshift-loader ?

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use another function, somehow missed it, I guess. I will try this one.